# Draggable scrollable sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I click on the DraggableHeaderComponent to pull it up, it doesn't work.

When dragging to the bottom of the screen, I want to keep the DraggableHeaderComponent sticky at the top and the rest of the array moving with the scroll.

The image below shows what I mean, but I want to install the header at the bottom.

[image]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      minChildSize: 0.145,
      initialChildSize: 0.145,
      expand: false,
      builder: (context, scrollController) => SafeArea(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                DraggableHeaderComponent(),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    controller: scrollController,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Component(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SizedBox.expand(
    child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
      minChildSize: 0.145,
      initialChildSize: 0.145,
      expand: false,
      builder: (context, scrollController) => SafeArea(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                DraggableHeaderComponent(),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    controller: scrollController,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Component(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
        ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

- Just add SizedBox.expand() widget after scaffold widget. Might work.

Comment: please click on arrow up button(this answer is useful) . thank you